# Fixed number and fixed rule in iterative process

Tags: scheme, sicp

I am reading [1.2  Procedures and the Processes They Generate](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-11.html) of SICP.

A linear iterative process to computing factorial

```
(define (factorial n)
  (fact-iter 1 1 n))

(define (fact-iter product counter max-count)
  (if (> counter max-count)
      product
      (fact-iter (* counter product)
                 (+ counter 1)
             max-count)))
```

Iteration:
product <--- counter · product
counter <--- counter + 1

Then illustrate that:

> At each step, all we need to keep track of, for any =n=, are the
>   current values of the variables product, counter, and max-count. We
>   call this an iterative process. In general, an iterative process is
>   one whose state can be summarized by
>   1) a fixed number of state
>   variables,
>   2) together with a fixed rule that describes how the
>   state variables should be updated as the process moves from state to
>   state
>   3) and an (optional) end test that specifies conditions
>   under which the process should terminate.     In computing n!, the
>   number of steps required grows linearly with n. Such a process is
>   called *a linear iterative process*.

Reference to the 1) fixed number 2) fixed rule and 3)optional end test

When I could confirm is that `max-count`is the 3) optional end test. but I am not sure about the fix number and fixed rule.

If fixed number is `counter` then fixed rule is `product=counter * product`, in this situation, counter is not fixed, it is counter += 1

If fixed number is counter and fixed rule is `counter + 1`, then they omit the greater rule of product and are too trivial.

What's the fixed number and fixed rule appropriately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context, a "fixed number" of variables means that there's a *limited* number of variables, known in advance when the process starts - we just have three of them: `product` `counter` and `max-count`. This is in contrast with a recursive process, which will have new copies of those three variables *per procedure call* in stack frames.

The second point is related: a "fixed rule" refers to the fact that in the recursive step of the procedure we simply call `fact-iter`, and there's nothing left to do after it executes: in other words, it's in *tail position*.

Comment: ty, got it. the fixed rule is `2) together with a fixed rule that describes how the state variables should be updated as the process moves from state to state`, so they are of counter+1 and counter * product.